# Interactive Brokers TWS not starting under Ubuntu with OpenJDK

Tags: interactive, ubuntu-12.04, broker

Error while starting up IBs TWS under Ubuntu 12.04. I looked up into stdout and found the following log message. I checked locales and tz settings but was not able to resolve it.

```
22:22:47:443 AWT-EventQueue-0: ERROR - No time zones could be retrieved from the OS
java.lang.Exception
    at twslaunch.jutils.fc.b(fc.java:354)
    at twslaunch.jutils.fc.s(fc.java:344)
    at twslaunch.jutils.gb.a(gb.java:147)
    at twslaunch.jutils.gb.f(gb.java:308)
    at feature.date.fc.<init>(fc.java:190)
    at feature.date.gc.<init>(gc.java:142)
    at feature.date.dc.<init>(dc.java:141)
    at feature.date.dc.<init>(dc.java:128)
    at feature.date.dc.<init>(dc.java:116)
    at jtscomponents.pq.<init>(pq.java:341)
    at jtscomponents.JTSDateCellEditor.newDateTimeEditorInstance(JTSDateCellEditor.java:340)
    at jcolumn.fc.run(fc.java:51)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at twslaunch.jtscomponents.j.a(j.java:74)
    at twslaunch.feature.welcome.j.h(j.java:425)
    at twslaunch.feature.welcome.j.a(j.java:408)
    at jclient.pl.<init>(pl.java:2628)
    at jconnection.b.h(b.java:181)
    at jconnection.b.e(b.java:56)
    at jconnection.a.b(a.java:199)
    at jconnection.rb.run(rb.java:158)
    at twslaunch.jutils.ec.a(ec.java:483)
    at jconnection.b.a(b.java:156)
    at jconnection.b.c(b.java:140)
    at jconnection.b.a(b.java:56)
    at jconnection.qb.run(qb.java:101)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reinstall `OpenJDK` and purge all files of the current java installation. I just found this by accident. So hopefully this helps other save some hours.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\* icedtea-\* icedtea6-\*
sudo aptitude install openjdk-7-jdk
```

The reason is not understood so far. I also tried to remove all TWS settings, but that did not work. the referenced tws.xml (in some forums was also not found).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but since it's not well known (enough) I would like to add that OpenJDK is NOT suppoerted by IB/TWS. You must use Oracle JDK.